# Render Transparent Background Fire Simulation

Tags: smoke-simulation, fire

[image][image]After many hours of research, I have yet to find a full tutorial explaining this. How can I go about rendering a fire simulation with a transparent background? I would prefer to use PNG as the file type. I changed the settings to render RGBA, and when I change go to Film->Transparent and check that box, I only see an alpha channel in that image. I can change the image to show the color channel, and my render is there, but I can't use this in After Effects. Please help!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You need to use OpenEXR for proper handling of emission and opacity at the same time (associated alpha). Not sure though how to solve your problem with After Effects.

Comment: I appreciate the advice! The render does not change though, unfortunately.